# How would we find the Christoffel symbols for $e^{2f(u,v)}(du^2 + dv^2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, partial-derivative

$$I = e^{2f(u,v)}(du^2 + dv^2)$$

From this you can read that

$E = G = e^{2f(u,v)}$ and $F = 0$. But I'm confused as to how to find $E_u$, $E_v$, $G_u$ and $G_v$.

I know for something in the form
$$ E = G = f(u,v),$$

I can write those as

$E_u = G_u = f_u$ and $E_v = G_v = f_v$

But I'm unsure how to do it for the one stated. Would it involve a chain rule of some type?

Like $E_u = e^{2f(u,v)}  (2f_u)$?

Comment: Yes, it's just chain rule.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks! So, my chain rule of that is correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Also, as an expansion of this, how would I find $l$, $m$, and $n$? I am actually calculating the fundamental theorem of surfaces with this and the Gauss/Codazzi equations and I need l,m, and n for those. All the problem says it that it has a completely generic second fundamental form.

Comment: There is no way to calculate the second fundamental form, which depends on the immersion (which is bot guven....)

Comment: So would I just leave that stuff as l, m, and n? My calculations for the fundamental Theorem of surfaces and for the Codazzi equations do use l, m, and n. It says it is generic.

Comment: I cannot comment further since I do not know problem are you working on... But this post have not given me any information to calculate $l, m, n$.

Comment: Okay thanks. The only additional information the problem gives is that the surface is confromally equivalent to the plane. And I'm asked to calculate the structure equations for the Gauss frame and the Gauss/Codazzi equations.

Comment: The problem is, every surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is locally conformal to the plane, that's a theorem of Chern. On the other hand, the plane and the cylinder has the same $I$ but different $l, m, n$. So it is not possible to get the second fundamental form from $I$ alone.